# Nuxt.js - How to use layout inside layout

Tags: layout, vue.js, components, nuxt.js

i have my deafult layout and i whant to make a page
with a layout and inside the layout a  component that will be change insdie and chacnge the url to

how i do that with nuxt?

somthing like this pic:
[image: https://prnt.sc/kl4zkc]

i have my base layout in red
and i have a page layout in blue
now i have a links ander the Dashbord and i want whnan i click on the links the black box inside change only by other component and the url chacnge to
but i didnt the nuxt call again to the blue layout

Comment: Please mark the second solution as the correct one to help others, What you are seeking for is called Nested routes.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue and solved by nesting pages using `<nuxt-child/>`.

[GIF: How it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebjWB.gif)

[GitHub: Nuxt.js Nested Routes Example Repository (not official)](https://github.com/dyanagi/nuxt-nested-routes-example)

Create a parent page like `pages/group-foo.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- ... -->
    <nuxt-child />
  </div>
</template>
```

Then, create a directory with the same name as the parent page: `pages/group-foo/`.

---

Also, see these official documents:

- [Nested Routes](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#nested-routes)
- [Dynamic Nested Routes](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#dynamic-nested-routes)
- [API: The  Component](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-child/)

Comment: Thanks, this works really well! Would you happen to know how to set a default route on the nested <nuxt-child> route?

Comment: Sorry, just figured it out, add an `index.vue` page to the `pages/group-foo/` directory!